# Xcode "Run With Performance Tool" disabled?

Tags: performance, xcode, debugging

I am trying to find memory leaks from my Xcode project. I don't know, what happened - I can't select anything from `Run->Run with performance tool` - the list of things are disabled.

Please help me, I am a beginner.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the CHUD tools (Shark, Instruments, etc) installed ? Or maybe you decided to move them and now Xcode can't find them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i have deleted the build folder and was trying to run with performance tool, without building the code again, if you need to test your app with performance tool, you must compiled your code, and you need to have build folder in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are building an iOS program. As said by Apple engineers, most items under Run with Performance Tool need dTrace support, but dTrace is not available for iOS yet, not even for simulators.