# xcode 3.2.5 Run with performance tool -> Zombies option disabled

Tags: xcode, ios, memory-leaks, instruments, nszombie

I have been developing for iOS but am new to Instruments. I was going through some tutorials for using instruments but most of them use Run with performance tool->object allocations, which is not present in my XCode (3.2.5) . If I select "Allocations" (which is present in my XCode), there is no option to select zombies (as is expected in Object Allocations). And also, Run with performance tool -> Zombies is disabled. Why does XCode disable the zombies option?

Answer (score 1):

This post talks about it: [Xcode "Run With Performance Tool" disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214604/xcode-run-with-performance-tool-disabled)

> I believe you are building an iOS program. As said by Apple engineers, most items under Run with Performance Tool need dTrace support, but dTrace is not available for iOS yet, not even for simulators.

I'm looking into this myself right now.  If I find out more, I'll update this post.  I was also hoping to use the Zombies performance tool for ios development.  :(

Update:  You might also look at [How to run iPhone program with Zombies instrument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417782/how-to-run-iphone-program-with-zombies-instrument) .  I'm going to try that out.

Comment: Apparently you can run the "Instruments" program independent of XCode and then attach it to either a running process or tell it the app you want to debug.  However, when I tried this, my app immediately kept crashing...  Not sure what that's about, but turns out I was able to determine the memory issue without it.

Hopefully these links were useful to you.